# Dealing with large number of json data over 700k in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, datareader

We have a separate tool to push the data to elasticsearch.
The tool is working fine when the records from SQL server are less or equal to 100k.

If the JSON has more than 100k records, it is throwing memory exception.

Is there any way to handle bulk records more than 100k?

Sample code is:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(SearchQuery, con);
SqlDataReader IndexReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
if (IndexReader.HasRows)
{
    DataTable IndexTable = new DataTable();
    IndexTable.Load(IndexReader);
    string Index_Push_data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IndexTable).ToString();
    JArray IndexArray = JArray.Parse(Index_Push_data);
    int DataCount = IndexArray.Count;
}
```

Comment: Many people won't know what lakh means.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Please explain what the code is trying to do, since it feels overly complicated. It appears to be reading some data into a `DataTable` (tip - consider using Dapper instead), then serialising the `DataTable` to JSON (why?), then calling `ToString` unnecessarily, then parsing the JSON _back_ to an object, then getting a count. This feels like a convoluted way to solve the issue.

Comment: this code is used to push the data elasticsearch, only one record can be pushed to elasticsearch at a time. IndexReader will have all the record which are returned from sql server. so we need to make it single record , so that the json wil be pushed to datatable and getting number of record as data count , then it will be processed using while loop.

Comment: Why put it in a `DataTable`? Why not use Dapper or EF to generate a list of all of the data? Then use `listName.Count` to get the list size (rather than going via JSON)?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. will check with Dapper.

Comment: Your title says 700k but the question talks about 100k. That's pretty confusing.

Comment: No Actually i need to push more than 700k record to elasticsearch. But im getting error as 'Memory exception'  if the json is having more than 100k records.